# Python ord() and chr()

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, chr, ord

I have:

```
txt = input('What is your sentence? ')  
list = [0]*128
for x in txt:
    list[ord(x)] += 1
for x in list:
        if x >= 1:
            print(chr(list.index(x)) * x)
```

As per my understanding this should just output every letter in a sentence like:

```
))
111
3333
etc.
```

For the string "aB)a2a2a2)" the output is correct:

```
))
222
B
aaaa
```

For the string "aB)a2a2a2" the output is wrong:

```
)
222
)
aaaa
```

I feel like all my bases are covered but I'm not sure what's wrong with this code.

Comment: So explain waht is wrong with your code

Comment: The output is wrong for the input “aB)a2a2a2“ it doesn’t even count letter B.

Comment: Don't use `list` as the name of a variable since it is the name of a builtin. In any event, `list.index(x)` doesn't really make sense. In context, `x` is an integer, and that integer can appear in multiple places in the list. In many cases, `index(x)` won't return the index that you actually want. Use `enumerate` instead.

Comment: For one thing don't name a variable `list`, it's the same name as the built-in type and could mess things up in strange ways.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `list.index(x)`, you're searching the list for the first index that value appears. That's not actually what you want though, you want the specific index of the value you just read, even if the same value occurs somewhere else earlier in the list too.

The best way to get indexes along side values from a sequence is with `enuemerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(list):
    if x >= 1:
        print(chr(i) * x)
```

That should get you the output you want, but there are several other things that would make your code easier to read and understand. First of all, using `list` as a variable name is a very bad idea, as that will shadow the builtin `list` type's name in your namespace. That makes it very confusing for anyone reading your code, and you even confuse yourself if you want to use the normal `list` for some purpose and don't remember you've already used it for a variable of your own.

The other issue is also about variable names, but it's a bit more subtle. Your two loops both use a loop variable named `x`, but the meaning of the value is different each time. The first loop is over the characters in the input string, while the latter loop is over the counts of each character. Using meaningful variables would make things a lot clearer.

Here's a combination of all my suggested fixes together:

```
text = input('What is your sentence? ')  
counts = [0]*128

for character in text:
    counts[ord(character)] += 1

for index, count in enumerate(counts):
        if count >= 1:
            print(chr(index) * count)
```

Comment: I often use the variable name `ch` instead of fully spelling out `character`, because it's easier to both type and read - yet it's symbolic enough to get the point across.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yeah, it's certainly not *necessary* to use full words like I did here, but sometimes the lines are so short and there are so few uses of each variable that it doesn't hurt! Even single letter variables are sometimes OK if they have clear semantic meaning (like `x` and `y` as coordinates, or `i` and `j` for indexes).